# Facebook API get_loggedin_user() suddenly returns null

Tags: facebook, api

I am using faecbook's PHP SDK and the `get_loggedin_user()` api worked good in past several weeks, but just about 10 minutes ago - it consistently returns null - does anybody know whether facebook is experience an outage or there is any change with this API?

My site is heavily rely on the facebook API - so any hints is highly appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

It means that user is logged out. You're using outdated version of PHP SDK, use new one instead

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

you can use

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

there

Comment: Genesis - thank you for your response. I'll take a look and update to the latest SDK.